# Error in Mysql export

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, export

This is the code I tried for exporting the database.

```
    //MysqlPath = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\"
    String executeCmd = "\"" +Mysqlpath+ " mysqldump -u " + dbUser
                + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r " + FilePath + "\\"
                + FileName;

    System.out.println(executeCmd);
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

I get the following error :

```
***Cannot run program """C:\Program": CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect***
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
File fMysqlPath = new File("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\");
String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUser
            + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r " + FilePath + "\\"
            + FileName;

System.out.println(executeCmd);
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd, null, fMysqlPath);
```

**Java 1.4.2**

Answer (score 2):

I hope this could help you , run dump command from java code

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u username -p password  databasename > /../.. datadump.sql");
```

Correct me if 'm wrong

Comment: Thanks @Stranger, this works for the local machine, but when I run the program in another machine, it shows an eoor as "Cannot find the file mysqldumb"

Comment: What you have used mysqldump or mysqldumb?

Comment: sorry @Stranger its mysqldump. I need a way to give the mysql installation path as in the mySqlPath